# Can't find error in ULS logs

Tags: error, uls, logs

I have a problem. When I get an error, I see that page with a correlation ID:

[image]

But I can't find the error in the ULS logs. In App Server logs is empty by this correlation ID. In FrontEnd Server, I found only this:

[image]

Why I don't have errors in logs?

Comment: Frontend server is showing the logs, you have to find for Level: Unexpected to see what's causing it

Comment: Hi, there isn't error for my correlation ID.

Comment: There should be, is that all the logs for that correlation ID?

Comment: Yes, that is all for that correlation ID.

Comment: Is your server is load balanced?

Comment: Hi, @little_big_thoughts! Does it matter?

Comment: Yes, you change your host entry to point specific server and check your server for those logs...

Comment: Does it worked??

Comment: @little_big_thoughts, I don't know about balancing. How can I check it? How can I change host?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a load balanced farm, your logs are spread across servers. You can use this PowerShell command to search across those logs for specific correlation IDs:

```
Merge-SPLogFile -path "D:\ErrorLog.txt" -Correlation "Your-error-correlation-id"
```

Documentation: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/Merge-SPLogFile?view=sharepoint-ps

If you still aren't finding your specific error, then the logging level of your farm may not be high enough. You can temporarily increase what is logged through Central Admin and then recreate the error (as possible).

Comment: Hi, @theChrisKent. I merged logs, but I found there only rows from my first post. In CA in Monitoring on both servers I cheked all categories and chose verbose and cklicked OK.

Comment: I found the problem. I increase logging level on both servers and saw errors, Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to check

1. Pick any server from your farm and get its `ipaddress`.
2. In you client machine `Run->drivers->host` open it in notepad(admin mode) and enter that `IP` along with webapp url `(i.e. 10.125.xxx.xx webapp.domain.com)`.
3. To double check it `Run->CMD->'Enter *ping webapp.domain.com*'` it should point you to the same server IP.
4. Now, All set re-iterate your issue, Then go to that server and look for that ID.

> **Note:** You should remove/comment that host entry after testing.